# Angular: Exclude time in Date comparison

Tags: angular, angular-moment

Here `this.startDate.value` is `Sun Aug 30 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` and `this.endDate.value` is `Sun Aug 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`. Since the time is different, comparison is working in this case.

```
if (moment(this.startDate.value).isAfter(moment(this.endDate.value,'day'))) {
    //
}
```

Is there any way to exclude time with this above comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked below code:

```
if (moment(this.startDate.value.format('YYYY-MM-DD')).isAfter(moment(this.endDate.value).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))) {
    //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in this way:

```
moment('2010-10-20').isAfter('2009-12-31', 'day'); // true
```

Also you can use year or month as granularity unit parma!

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8smqcx23/) to test it.

Comment: check the fiddle above !